# Faster Approach of Double for loop when iterating large list (18,895 elements)

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, csv, for-loop

Here's the code:

```
import csv
import re

with open('alcohol_rehab_ltp.csv', 'rb') as csv_f, \
    open('cities2.txt', 'rb') as cities, \
    open('drug_rehab_city_state.csv', 'wb') as out_csv:
    writer = csv.writer(out_csv, delimiter = ",")
    reader = csv.reader(csv_f)
    city_lst = cities.readlines()

    for row in reader:
        for city in city_lst:
            city = city.strip()
            match = re.search((r'\b{0}\b').format(city), row[0])
            if match:
                writer.writerow(row)
                break
```

"alcohol_rehab_ltp.csv" has 145 lines, and "cities2.txt" has 18,895 lines (which becomes 18,895 when converted to the list). It takes a while for this process to run, I haven't timed but maybe around 5 minutes. Is there something simple (or more complex) that I am overlooking here, that could make this script run more quickly. I will be using other .csv files to run against the large text file of "cities.txt", and these csv files may have anywhere up to 1000 lines. Any ideas on how to speed things up would be appreciated!
Here is csv file:Keywords (144),Avg. CPC,Local Searches,Advertiser Competition

```
[alcohol rehab san diego],$49.54,90,High
[alcohol rehab dallas],$86.48,110,High
[alcohol rehab atlanta],$60.93,50,High
[free alcohol rehab centers],$11.88,110,High
[christian alcohol rehab centers],–,70,High
[alcohol rehab las vegas],$33.40,70,High
[alcohol rehab cost],$57.37,110,High
```

some lines from text file:

```
san diego
dallas
atlanta
dallas
los angeles
denver
```

Comment: The nested loops size is relatively small (18895 x 145 iteration). Have you timed the code in any way? Are you sure that the bottleneck that makes you wait 5 minutes is the loop indeed?

If it is so, I would try to get rid of the regular expression in favor of a string split by non-letter characters and do `if city in row.split(r'\W'):` (hoist the split out of the "cities" loop)

Comment: When I actually measured it, it was 2 mins 30 seconds. I hadn't used datetime before, so i'm glad Shawn Zhang added it to his code so I could see how to use that.

Comment: why are you using re?

Comment: Can you show some of your input as I think you are doing a lot more work than you need to

Comment: I am using re because the name of cities will be contained in the first column of each row of the csv. For example, the row 2 column 1 contains "san diego alcohol rehab center" and "san diego" will be one of the lines in the text file. I hadn't come up with a better alternative with what I know.

Comment: ok will add input to the opening post

Comment: ok input has been added

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Build a single regex with all the city names:

```
city_re = re.compile(r'\b('+ '|'.join(c.strip() for c in cities.readlines()) + r')\b')
```

and then do:

```
for row in reader:
    match = city_re.search(row[0])
    if match:
        writer.writerow(row)
```

This will reduce the number of loop iterations from 18895 x 145 to only 18895 with the regex engine doing its best at string prefix matching on those 145 city names.

For your convenience and testing, here is the full listing:

```
import csv
import re

with open('alcohol_rehab_ltp.csv', 'rb') as csv_f, \
    open('cities2.txt', 'rb') as cities, \
    open('drug_rehab_city_state.csv', 'wb') as out_csv:
    writer = csv.writer(out_csv, delimiter = ",")
    reader = csv.reader(csv_f)

    city_re = re.compile(r'\b('+ '|'.join(c.strip() for c in cities.readlines()) + r')\b')

    for row in reader:
        match = city_re.search(row[0])
        if match:
            writer.writerow(row)
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you can use a `set` and indexing:

```
with open('alcohol_rehab_ltp.csv', 'rb') as csv_f, \
    open('cities2.txt', 'rb') as cities, \
    open('drug_rehab_city_state.csv', 'wb') as out_csv:
    writer = csv.writer(out_csv, delimiter = ",")
    space = ""
    reader = csv.reader(csv_f)
    # make set of all city names, lookups are 0(1)
    city_set = {line.rstrip() for line in cities}
    output_list = []
    header = next(reader) # skip header
    for row in reader:
        try:
            # names are either first or last with two words preceding or following 
            # so split twice on whitespace from either direction
            if row[0].split(None,2)[-1].rstrip("]") in city_set or row[0].rsplit(None, 2)[0][1:] in city_set:
                output_list.append(row)
        except IndexError as e:
            print(e,row[0])
    writer.writerows(output_list)
```

Running time is now `0(n)` as opposed to quadratic.

Answer (score 2):

First, as @Shawn Zhang suggests `(r'\b{0}\b').format(c.strip())` can be outside loop, and you can create result list, to avoid writing to file in each iteration.

Second, you might try `re.compile` to compile regular expression, that might improve your performance on regular expression.

Third, try to profile it a little bit to find the bottleneck, e.g. with `timeit` or other profiler like `ica` if you have SciPy.

Also, if city is always in first column, and I assume that it's named 'City' why don't you use `csv.DictReader()` to read csv? I'm sure it's faster than regular expression.

#### EDIT

As you provided example of your file I get rid of `re` (because it seems you really don't need them), and got that more than 10 time faster with code as below:

```
import csv

with open('alcohol_rehab_ltp.csv', 'rb') as csv_f, \
    open('cities2.txt', 'rb') as cities, \
    open('drug_rehab_city_state.csv', 'wb') as out_csv:
    writer = csv.writer(out_csv, delimiter = ",")
    output_list = []
    reader = csv.reader(csv_f)
    city_lst = cities.readlines()

    for row in reader:
        for city in city_lst:
            city = city.strip()
            if city in row[0]:
                output_list.append(row)
    writer.writerows(output_list)
```

Comment: iterating on tuples is not faster, you just added more overhead by converting a list to a tuple. The algorithm is quadratic that is the bottleneck.

Comment: Ok, I leave 'tuple' idea. I heard that they are faster, but maybe I lost something.

Comment: they can be  faster to create as they are immutable so they don't need to allocate any extra space but there is no difference iterating over one.

Answer (score 1):

Even though I don't think the loop/IO is big bottleneck,but still if you can try to start with them.

There two tips I could provide:
`(r'\b{0}\b').format(c.strip())` can be in outside the loop ,that will increase some performance, because we don't have to strip(), format on in each loop.

also ,you don't have to write output result in each loop, instead, you can create a result list `ouput_list` save the result during the loop and write them once after the loop.

```
import csv
import re
import datetime

start = datetime.datetime.now()

with open('alcohol_rehab_ltp.csv', 'rb') as csv_f, \
    open('cities2.txt', 'rb') as cities, \
    open('drug_rehab_city_state.csv', 'wb') as out_csv:
    writer = csv.writer(out_csv, delimiter = ",")
    space = ""
    reader = csv.reader(csv_f)
    city_lst = [(r'\b{0}\b').format(c.strip()) for c in cities.readlines()]
    output_list = []
    for row in reader:
        for city in city_lst:
            #city = city.strip()
            match = re.search(city, row[0])
            if match:
                output_list.append(row)
                break
    writer.writerows(output_list)



end = datetime.datetime.now()

print end -  start
```

Comment: Thanks, that knocked 5 seconds off, from 2 mins 30 to 2 mins 25.

Answer (score 1):

Please note that I assume that you can use a better way than using `re.search` for finding city in row, since generally the city will be separated by a delimiter like space. Otherwise it is a complexity greater than O(n*m)

One way could be to use a hashtable.

```
ht = [0]*MAX
```

Read all the cities (assuming these are in thousands) and fill up a hashtable

```
ht[hash(city)] = 1
```

Now when you iterate across each row in reader,

```
for row in reader:
    for word in row:
        if ht[hash(word)] == 1:
            # found, do stuff here
            pass
```